# A bitmap from many of them

Tags: android, performance, bitmap, android-canvas, bitmapfactory

Guys I have a solution to crate a bitmap from 5 different another ones. However, I want this solution to be faster. I could not find another easy and fast way to do same.

```
private void createImage() {
    // Magic numbers from image files
    int numberOfImages = 5;
    int imgWidth = 125;
    int imgHeight = 300;
    int totalwidth = imgWidth * numberOfImages;
    int totalheight = imgHeight;


    img = Bitmap.createBitmap(totalwidth, totalheight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfImages; i++) {
        Bitmap imgFile = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), context.getResources().getIdentifier(
                "f" + i, "drawable", context.getPackageName()));
        for (int x = 0; x < imgWidth; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < imgHeight; y++) {
                int targetX = x + (i * imgWidth);
                int targetY = y;
                int color = imgFile.getPixel(x, targetY);
                img.setPixel(targetX, targetY, color);
            }
        }
    }


    img = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(img, screenWidth, screenHeight, true);

}
```

Comment: Have you considered combining your bitmaps offline (using your favorite image editor), then just load it in as a single resource?

Comment: @SchighSchagh No, it is something unsuitable for my project but thx :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mostly there. You've created a bitmap that is wide enough for them all.

What you then need to do is draw the bitmaps directly onto it one at a time, but the whole bitmap at once, not pixel by pixel.

You can do this using something call [`Canvas`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html). Which aids in drawing things onto bitmaps.

```
img = Bitmap.createBitmap(totalwidth, totalheight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas drawCanvas = new Canvas(img);

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfImages; i++) {
    Bitmap imgFile = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), context.getResources().getIdentifier(
            "f" + i, "drawable", context.getPackageName()));

          // Draw bitmap onto combo bitmap, at offset x, y.
          drawCanvas.drawBitmap(imgFile, i * imgWidth, 0, null);


}
```

Comment: Sir it is something what I reallt needed. Thank you so much. Also, I have learned a new way of working with images in android thanks to you. Bests.

Comment: @ErayTuncer Glad I was of help :). With Canvas, you can draw all sorts onto the Bitmap. Other bitmaps, Text, lines, points, squares circles... :) Take a look at the Canvas like when you get time. Also, if you Dont need alpha channel (see through layers), use `Bitmap.Config.RGB_565` to save on memory.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine the `Bitmap.getPixels()` and `Bitmap.setPixels()` methods might help.

```
private void createImage() {
    // Magic numbers from image files
    int numberOfImages = 5;
    int imgWidth = 125;
    int imgHeight = 300;
    int totalwidth = imgWidth * numberOfImages;
    int totalheight = imgHeight;


    img = Bitmap.createBitmap(totalwidth, totalheight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    int buf[] = new int[totalwidth * totalheight];

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfImages; ++i) {
        Bitmap imgFile = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
            context.getResources().getIdentifier(
                "f" + i, "drawable", context.getPackageName()));
        imgFile.getPixels(buf, i*imgWidth, totalwidth, 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);
    }
    img.setPixels(buf, 0, totalwidth, 0, 0, totalwidth, totalheight);

    img = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(img, screenWidth, screenHeight, true);

}
```

I have not tried it, but based on [the](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#setPixels%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixels%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29), I think it should work. I imagine it will hopefully be considerably faster since we do all the work with only 6 function calls, assuming that under the covers those functions do something much more clever than just looping over the array (such as direct memory copy).

Comment: Sir, your implementation works at the same speed as Doomsknight's. However, yours looks little confusing for me. I do not know how to use setPixels and getPixels methods very well but I will work on from now thanks to you. Bests :)

Comment: The documentation should help explain how they work. Briefly, `buf[]` is a temporary buffer to hold all the pixels. Even though it's allocated as a 1D array, `getPixels` interprets it as a 2D array. ie, `buf[0]` is row 0, col 0; `buf[2*totalwidth+3]` is row 2, col 3. `getPixels` simply copies the `Bitmap` into the appropriate part of `buf[]`. The `i*imgWidth` part is the index into `buf` for where the upper-left corner of `imgFile` should go. The `totalwidth` parameter tells `getPixels` the width of `buf[]` as a 2D array. The `0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight` parameters dictate getting all pixels.

Answer (score 1):

The Doomsknight's answer seems correct to me but you should not do this kind of processes on the main thread for Android. Too many images might hit the [16ms barrier](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/performance.html#measure).

You can do this in background handler thread and update the UI Thread after finished.

```
HandlerThread cropperHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("background_cropper");
cropperHandlerThread.start();
// Do not call getLooper before start handler thread.
Handler cropperHandler = new Handler(cropperHandlerThread.getLooper());
cropperHandler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Create Bitmap Here
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Update ImageView here
            }
        });
    }
});
```